# JBOSS (6.3.3 GA) standalone xml- CLI to add logging failed

Tags: logging, jboss, command-line-interface

i was trying to add logging with "DEBUG" level to my standalone xml file, but i got the following message in jboss.

```
INFO: try block failed: {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => "JBAS014807: Management resource '[
    (\"subsystem\" => \"logging\"),
    (\"logger\" => \"com.example\")
]' not found"}}
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*my cli*

```
try
/subsystem="logging"/logger="com.example":add(category="com.example",level="DEBUG")
catch
end-try
```

Comment: Nothing added/changed on standalone xml file.

Comment: How are you executing the CLI script? Are you using the wildfly-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes :
/subsystem=logging/logger=com.example:add(category="com.example",level="DEBUG")